FetchData работа с xml
помогите есть сайт на котором лежит xml файл
https://пример.com/export/xml/com.xml
Со структурой
<test>
<date yesterday="25.09.2024" today="26.09.2024" tomorrow="27.09.2024" tomorrow02="28.09.2024"/>
<test1>
<yesterday>Вчера</yesterday>
<today>Сегодня </today>
<tomorrow>Завтра</tomorrow>
<tomorrow02>тоже текст</tomorrow02>
</test1>

Как мне из этого xml получить текст из tomorrow02 например и записать в переменную.
С переменной разберусь, как мне этот текст хотя бы в консоле показать

Можно попробовать вот и тут на русском примеры


Как мне из этого xml получить текст из tomorrow02 например и записать в переменную.

Такое можно реализовать, например, вот таким образом...


const s = `<test>
<date yesterday="25.09.2024" today="26.09.2024" tomorrow="27.09.2024" tomorrow02="28.09.2024"/>
<test1>
<yesterday>Вчера</yesterday>
<today>Сегодня </today>
<tomorrow>Завтра</tomorrow>
<tomorrow02>тоже текст</tomorrow02>
</test1>`

const xml = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(s, "text/xml")
const v = xml.querySelector('test1 tomorrow02').textContent
console.log(v)



Для запроса на некий сервер такое может выглядеть вот так...
fetch('некий_УРЛ_ресурса')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(xml => console.log(xml.querySelector('tomorrow02').textContent));


Я примерно этого добиться и пытаюсь, только файл xml находится на другом сайте, как мне в const s вывести инфу из xml с другого сайта

@UsbFan, отправить запрос fetch... Получить ответ как текст... Далее все как в моем примере.

Ты лучший, это то что мне надо было, ещё один маленький вопрос, если у меня в таблице
<tomorrow02>тоже текст</tomorrow02>
</test1>  <test2>
<tomorrow02>тоже текст</tomorrow02>
</test2>``` как можно выбрать из какого test  tomorrow02 показывать?

Всё, чёт я тупанул, спасибо, разобрался))

@UsbFan, нужно селектор немного усложнить, добавить родителя... test1 tomorrow02 или test2 tomorrow02. Будет выбран нужный тебе элемент. В примере я дописал это.
